# SMS messages not sending using webservices in visualforce page?

Tags: apex, visualforce, webservices, callout

Hi i m tring to send sms using webservices through visualforce page.
but i m not getting any message

these two are my wsdl apex classes:

```
public class wwwWebservicexNet2 {
    public class SendSMSToIndia_element {
        public String MobileNumber;
        public String FromEmailAddress;
        public String Message;
        private String[] MobileNumber_type_info = new String[]{'MobileNumber','http://www.webserviceX.NET',null,'0','1','false'};
        private String[] FromEmailAddress_type_info = new String[]{'FromEmailAddress','http://www.webserviceX.NET',null,'0','1','false'};
        private String[] Message_type_info = new String[]{'Message','http://www.webserviceX.NET',null,'0','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://www.webserviceX.NET','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'MobileNumber','FromEmailAddress','Message'};
    }
    public class SMSResult {
        public String FromEmailAddress;
        public String MobileNumber;
        public String Provider;
        public String State;
        public String Status;
        private String[] FromEmailAddress_type_info = new String[]{'FromEmailAddress','http://www.webserviceX.NET',null,'0','1','false'};
        private String[] MobileNumber_type_info = new String[]{'MobileNumber','http://www.webserviceX.NET',null,'0','1','false'};
        private String[] Provider_type_info = new String[]{'Provider','http://www.webserviceX.NET',null,'0','1','false'};
        private String[] State_type_info = new String[]{'State','http://www.webserviceX.NET',null,'0','1','false'};
        private String[] Status_type_info = new String[]{'Status','http://www.webserviceX.NET',null,'0','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://www.webserviceX.NET','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'FromEmailAddress','MobileNumber','Provider','State','Status'};
    }
    public class SendSMSToIndiaResponse_element {
        public wwwWebservicexNet2.SMSResult SendSMSToIndiaResult;
        private String[] SendSMSToIndiaResult_type_info = new String[]{'SendSMSToIndiaResult','http://www.webserviceX.NET',null,'0','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://www.webserviceX.NET','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'SendSMSToIndiaResult'};
    }
    public class SendSMSSoap {
        public String endpoint_x = 'http://www.webservicex.net/SendSMS.asmx';
        public Map<String,String> inputHttpHeaders_x;
        public Map<String,String> outputHttpHeaders_x;
        public String clientCertName_x;
        public String clientCert_x;
        public String clientCertPasswd_x;
        public Integer timeout_x;
        private String[] ns_map_type_info = new String[]{'http://www.webserviceX.NET', 'wwwWebservicexNet2'};
        public wwwWebservicexNet2.SMSResult SendSMSToIndia(String MobileNumber,String FromEmailAddress,String Message) {
            wwwWebservicexNet2.SendSMSToIndia_element request_x = new wwwWebservicexNet2.SendSMSToIndia_element();
            request_x.MobileNumber = MobileNumber;
            request_x.FromEmailAddress = FromEmailAddress;
            request_x.Message = Message;
            wwwWebservicexNet2.SendSMSToIndiaResponse_element response_x;
            Map<String, wwwWebservicexNet2.SendSMSToIndiaResponse_element> response_map_x = new Map<String, wwwWebservicexNet2.SendSMSToIndiaResponse_element>();
            response_map_x.put('response_x', response_x);
            WebServiceCallout.invoke(
              this,
              request_x,
              response_map_x,
              new String[]{endpoint_x,
              'http://www.webserviceX.NET/SendSMSToIndia',
              'http://www.webserviceX.NET',
              'SendSMSToIndia',
              'http://www.webserviceX.NET',
              'SendSMSToIndiaResponse',
              'wwwWebservicexNet2.SendSMSToIndiaResponse_element'}
            );
            response_x = response_map_x.get('response_x');
            return response_x.SendSMSToIndiaResult;
        }
    }
}
```

Another class

```
public class AsyncWwwWebservicexNet2 {
    public class SendSMSToIndiaResponse_elementFuture extends System.WebServiceCalloutFuture {
        public wwwWebservicexNet2.SMSResult getValue() {
            wwwWebservicexNet2.SendSMSToIndiaResponse_element response = (wwwWebservicexNet2.SendSMSToIndiaResponse_element)System.WebServiceCallout.endInvoke(this);
            return response.SendSMSToIndiaResult;
        }
    }
    public class AsyncSendSMSSoap {
        public String endpoint_x = 'http://www.webservicex.net/SendSMS.asmx';
        public Map<String,String> inputHttpHeaders_x;
        public String clientCertName_x;
        public Integer timeout_x;
        private String[] ns_map_type_info = new String[]{'http://www.webserviceX.NET', 'wwwWebservicexNet2'};
        public AsyncWwwWebservicexNet2.SendSMSToIndiaResponse_elementFuture beginSendSMSToIndia(System.Continuation continuation,String MobileNumber,String FromEmailAddress,String Message) {
            wwwWebservicexNet2.SendSMSToIndia_element request_x = new wwwWebservicexNet2.SendSMSToIndia_element();
            request_x.MobileNumber = MobileNumber;
            request_x.FromEmailAddress = FromEmailAddress;
            request_x.Message = Message;
            return (AsyncWwwWebservicexNet2.SendSMSToIndiaResponse_elementFuture) System.WebServiceCallout.beginInvoke(
              this,
              request_x,
              AsyncWwwWebservicexNet2.SendSMSToIndiaResponse_elementFuture.class,
              continuation,
              new String[]{endpoint_x,
              'http://www.webserviceX.NET/SendSMSToIndia',
              'http://www.webserviceX.NET',
              'SendSMSToIndia',
              'http://www.webserviceX.NET',
              'SendSMSToIndiaResponse',
              'wwwWebservicexNet2.SendSMSToIndiaResponse_element'}
            );
        }
    }
}
```

my Controller Class:

```
public class sendsms{
public string FromEmailAddress{get;set;}
public string MobileNumber{get;set;}
public String Message{get;set;}
public String result{get;set;}

public string send(){
wwwWebservicexNet2.SendSMSSoap sms = new wwwWebservicexNet2.SendSMSSoap();
sms.SendSMSToIndia(MobileNumber,FromEmailAddress,Message);
return null;
}
}
```

My doubt is while generating wsdl file two apex classes created in that what class i will use in controller class and any error in my controller class why i am not getting any message please help on this

Comment: Ok thank you... is it correct my controller class is there any issues?... please tell me

Comment: which mobile operator you are using?  we can use only `Airtel,Idea Cellular,Skycell ,RPG Cellular,Hutch,Celforce / Fascel,BPL Mobile,Escotel` numbers

Comment: Airtel Mobile number

Comment: have you tried in official test section http://www.webservicex.net/WS/WSDetails.aspx?CATID=4&WSID=59.. If yes then may be issue in server

Comment: Yes i tried in that site i didn't get any message

Comment: is your number register with DND? if yes then try another number.